# Facebook Open Graph returns 404?

Tags: facebook, wordpress, facebook-graph-api

I have this website: http://www.boxlifemagazine.com/training/staticvsdynamicstretching that when I go to open graph it returns me a 404 error, even if the page is loading. The plugin that I have installed in wordpress puts everything in the header of the website. I do not understand what it is wrong: I've tried all the suggested ( from other posts from here ) things to be done: disable and re-enable plugins, rebuild permalinks structure, etc. But nothing works.

Here is the error: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.boxlifemagazine.com%2Ftraining%2Fstaticvsdynamicstretching

Comment: There’s little we can do to determine the cause of this problem from the outside. Since no 404 is sent when the page is requested through a normal browser, your wordpress must react differently when the FB scraper requests it – as to why, we can only speculate. Might be some plugin “protecting” against requests through bots or something.

Comment: Well, I've spent my day to check for this bug. I have deactivated all plugins, and everything else and it seems that there is no problem with the other plugins. The only thing that I see it is that there are 2 tickets submited to Facebook as this being a boog. And both approved. Also the crawler is whitelisted, and everything works well on my .htaccess file. I cannot find a workaround for this though..

Comment: @roshkattu, how you solved it?

Comment: New API implementation. The API has changed